# how can i call the list in the resttemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

1-this my model object for account , iwant to return a json result for post method and my problem that my code return null .=

```
public class Account implements Serializable {

   
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long id;
    private String accountType;
    private String title;
    private double lockedAmount;
    private String lastUpdate;
    private double balance;
    private String currency;
    private String rib;
    private String Agency;
    private String swiftcode;
    private String ribURI;
    private boolean canDebit;
    private boolean canCredit;
    private List<Operation> operation;
    private List<Documents> documents;
```

2-this the class Operation :

```
public class Operation {

    private String Descript;
    private String ValueDate;
    private String bookDate;
    private String Reference;
    private Integer Debit;
    private Integer Credit;
    private Integer ClosingBalance;

}
```

3-this is what i do in my controller :

```
  //get Operation list by account id 
    @PostMapping("eAccount/Operations/Account/{id}")
    public List<Operation> getOperationsByAccountId(@PathVariable long id, String bookDate) {
        return operationService.getOperationsByAccountId(id, bookDate);
    }
```

4-and the service :

```
    //get Operation list by account id 
    public List<Operation> getOperationsByAccountId(@PathVariable long id, String bookDate) {
        Account account = new Account();
        
        account.setId(id);
        String url = operationUrl;
        account = resttemplate.postForObject(url,account, Account.class);
      
        return account.getOperation();
    }
```

5-i need to return this result :

```
{   "account": {     "id": "100000000137",     
"operation": [       
{        
 "bookDate": "20160105 20160201"       }     ]   } }
```

Comment: debug here account = resttemplate.postForObject(url,account, Account.class);, it seems the account.getOperation() is returning null

Comment: I don't understand what do you means by it seems ?

Comment: This question is very ambiguous. Is Account and operation model for post request object? It looks like this is more of a get method than post and account is response object. Please clarify

Comment: The code you have should work, but without describing the API that you integrate with, we cannot provide any help. What's the request model, what is the response model, what exact result you see when calling the api.

Comment: @DrashtiDobariya yaaa account and operation is a model for pst request object , ya the get method is working but i need to do this with post method not get

Comment: @NicoVanBelle this the flux what i need as a response ``` {   "account": {     "id": "100000000137",     
"operation": [       
{        
 "bookDate": "20160105 20160201"       }     ]   } } ```

Comment: what is the model for request object for third party url?

Comment: We know what you need but we don't know what you currently have, nor do we have any API documentation. It's like asking "I created a method but it does not return the expected result when calling with parameter x" and then not provide any details of the method. How can anyone solve that mistery?

Comment: this is the url  
   ` @Value(value = "${operation.Url:null}")
    private String operationUrl;`  and in the application.propreties i call the json file operation.Url= http://172.27.224.1:3333/RestEndPoint/ebanking/account/getStmt